Markov chain question : Calculating lim[n→∞] P(X[n+1] = X[1])
i have the following matrix, and $P(X_0=i)$ i=[1,3] is also given:


the question is to calculate $lim_{n\to \infty}$ $P(X_{n+1} = X_1)$  .

what i did is:

I've found the stationary distribution $\pi$i = $1/3$
i calculated $P(X_1 = i)$ : $P(X_1 = 1) = 0.25$ , $P(X_1 = 2) =0.125$ , $P(X_1 = 3) =0.625$
from here my calculation is :
$$\sum_{i=1}^3\ lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_{n+1} = i)*P(X_1 = i)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^3\ \pi_i*P(X_1 = i)$$
$$\frac13 (\frac5{32}+\frac{21}{40}+\frac{51}{160}) =\frac13$$

My main consideration is: Since we're asked about $X_{n+1}$ and not $X_n$, do I need to make one additional transition after reaching the stationary distribution? In other words, should I multiply the stationary distribution by the transition matrix one more time before calculating the final probability?
I'm unsure if this additional step is necessary or if the stationary distribution already accounts for this. (in this specific question, and in general)

If you multiply the stationary distribution $\pi$ by the transition matrix $ \mathcal{P}$ you end up with the stationary distribution. That is the definition of stationary distribution: $\pi \mathcal{P}=\pi.$
In the end the limit accounts for the fact, that you do not have to worry about the $n+1$, because for a convergent sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ it is known that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1},$$
which in this example means:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_{n+1}=X_1)=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_n=X_1).$$
I want to stress another thing: For a Markov chain $X_n$ you can not split $P(X_m=i,X_k=j)$ like $P(X_m=i,X_k=j)=P(X_m=i)(X_k=j)$, because $X_k$ and $X_m$ are not necessarily independent random variables. Instead you can write:
$$P(X_m=i,X_k=j)=P(X_m=i|X_k=j)P(X_k=j).$$
Taking this into account, we can now use your approach and calculate:
$$P(X_{n+1} = X_1)=\sum_{i=1}^3 P(X_{n+1} = i,X_1 = i)=\sum_{i=1}^3 P(X_{n+1} = i|X_1 = i)P(X_1=i).$$
From $\mathcal{P}$ we can conclude that $X_n$ is an irreducible and thus ergodic Markov chain. By the ergodic theorem we infer:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_{n+1} = i|X_1 = i)= \lim_{n\to \infty}  \mathcal{P}^n_{ii}=\pi_i=\frac{1}{3}.$$
This then gives your result $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X_{n+1} = X_1)=\frac{1}{3}$.
